# Dart/Polymer binding object attributes of a list

Tags: data-binding, dart, polymer

I am trying to bind to the attributes of objects in a list. The list is made observable by using `toObservable`. Now I bind all the elements with polymer. Works fine. If a add an object to the list the update works also fine. But there is no update if the attributes of the objects in the list is changed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you share some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss `extends Object with Observable` of the class declaration and/or the `@observable` annotation of the property declaration as shown below:

```dart
class YourListItem extends Object with Observable {
  @observable aProperty;
}
```

If this doesn't help please provide the code of the objects you put into the list in your question.